# Sort array of numbers by normal distribution (gaussian distribution)

Tags: javascript, sorting, gaussian, normal-distribution

Having an array of numbers `setOfNumbers = [0, 3, 3, 2, 7, 1, -2, 9]` I'd like to sort this set to have the smallest numbers on the end and beginning and the biggest in the center of the sorted set like this `sortedSetNumbers = [0, 2, 3, 9, 7, 3, 1, -2]`.

```js
const setOfNumbers = [0, 3, 3, 2, 7, 1, -2, 9];
const result = [0, 2, 3, 9, 7, 3, 1, -2];

function sortNormal(a, b) {
  return true; // Please, change this line
}

const sortedSetNumbers = setOfNumbers.sort((a, b) => sortNormal(a, b));



if (sortedSetNumbers === result) {
  console.info('Succeeded Normal Distributed');
} else {
  console.warn('Failed Normal Distribution');
}

console.log(sortedSetNumbers);
```

I am sure it is possible to sort these numbers with the method `Array.prototype.sort()`, but how should this sorting function look like?

**EDIT:** The solution does not have to be solved with `.sort()`. That was only an idea.

Comment: Perhaps I'm naive to how this distribution works, but how do you determine which numbers are put to the beginning, and which to the end? Or does it not matter?

Comment: It does not really matter. The result does not have to be exactly the one in the answer. I've done it manually. The steps where 1) Pick biggest number 2) Find next biggest number of left set 3) Append altering left and right to the the result set.

Comment: @OliverRadini max number in between less than max in right and greater than max in left

Comment: @all If the question is not clear enough and you think you've understood my problem, feel free to edit the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be the most naive way to do it, but isn't it simply left, right, left, right... after sorting?

```js
const input    = [0, 3, 3, 2, 7, 1, -2, 9];
const expected = [0, 2, 3, 9, 7, 3, 1, -2];

const sorted   = input.slice().sort();
const output   = [];
let side       = true;

while (sorted.length) {
  output[side ? 'unshift' : 'push'](sorted.pop());
  side = !side;
}

console.log(expected.join());
console.log(output.join());
```

---

Or simply:

```js
const input  = [0, 3, 3, 2, 7, 1, -2, 9];
const output = input.slice().sort().reduceRight((acc, val, i) => {
  return i % 2 === 0 ? [...acc, val] : [val, ...acc];
}, []);

console.log(output.join());
```

Comment: Impressive, both of you @Yoshi and @NinaScholz!

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach is to sort the array ascending.

Get another array of the indices and sort the odds into the first half asending and the even values to the end descending with a inverted *butterfly shuffle*.

Then map the sorted array by taking the value of the sorted indices.

> ```
> [-2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 7,  9] // sorted array
> [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 6, 4, 2,  0] // sorted indices
> [ 0, 2, 3, 9, 7, 3, 1, -2] // rebuild sorted array
> ```

```js
var array = [0, 3, 3, 2, 7, 1, -2, 9].sort((a, b) => a - b);

array = Array
    .from(array, (_, i) => i)
    .sort((a, b) => b % 2 - a % 2 || (a % 2 ? a - b : b - a))
    .map(i => array[i]);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not really elegant, but it does it's job.

```js
const setOfNumbers = [0, 3, 3, 2, 7, 1, -2, 9];
const alternation = alternate();
const sortedSetNumbers = sortNormal(setOfNumbers);

function sortNormal(start) {
  const result = [];
  const interim = start.sort((a, b) => {
    return b - a;
  });

  interim.map(n => {
    if (alternation.next().value) {
      result.splice(0, 0, n);
    } else {
      result.splice(result.length, 0, n);
    }
  });

  return result;
}

function* alternate() {
  let i = true;

  while (true) {
    yield i;
    i = !i;
  }
}

console.log(sortedSetNumbers);
```